# PayPal Style Date input

Tags: jquery, html, validation, input

I am designing a signup form. I am fascinated by PayPal's signup form where we can only type numeric on date and it automatically seperates them using "/" and we can't add more numbers. here is link https://www.paypal.com/signup/create?country.x=AU

I would like to know how this is done.
this is what i found while ispecting.

```
<input type="text" id="dob" maxlength="10" value="" pattern="(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])/(([0][1-9])|([1][0-2]))/((1|2)[0-9]{3})" name="dob" required="required" class="hasHelp validate userText" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" aria-required="true" data-placeholder-text="DD/MM/YYYY" data-label="Date of birth" data-format="ddmmyyyy" data-today="19/07/2015" data-separator="/" aria-invalid="false">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use one of jQuery's inputmask plugins.
Here is one for example: http://robinherbots.github.io/jquery.inputmask/

There is a demo there and you can [download it from here](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask).

Answer (score 0):

HTML 5 has a pattern attribute for the input element, which Paypal implements:

`pattern="(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])/(([0][1-9])|([1][0-2]))/((1|2)[0-9]{3})"`

You can find more info on that on the web, for instance this spec on [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#attr-pattern).